# Event binding gets removed after saving and reloading stage in KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

Below is my code, am loading an image and binding onclick event to it. What i want is to save this stage and draw something else i.e next screen with back button, back button will load previous screen. But when i save stage using json and reload stage, stage shows all ok, but on click event is removed from image. can any one help, i want to be able to have that previous screen as it is with all elements and their events. is there another way then using json which can do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="js/kinetic-v4.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadImages(sources, callback){
    var assetDir = 'http://localhost/kineticdemo/images/';
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources){
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function(){
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages){
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = assetDir + sources[src];
    }
}

function initStage(images)
{
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 730,
      height: 700
    });
    var outerLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var logo = new Kinetic.Image({
              image:images.logo,
              x:450,
              y:75,
              id:"logo"
            });

    logo.on('click',function(){
        alert('aaa');
    });

    outerLayer.add(logo);
    stage.add(outerLayer);

    var json = stage.toJSON();
    stage.destroy();
    stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');
    stage.get('#logo').apply('setImage',images.logo);
    stage.draw();
}
var sources = {
    logo: 'logo.png'
};
loadImages(sources, initStage);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, KineticJS serializes Node properties, but it doesn’t serialize Node event handlers.

So, the rehydrated stage will know which nodes are “listening”, but you must manually re-bind the event handlers:

**Re-hydrating the click event handler**

```
// re-bind event listener
stage.get('#logo').on('click',  function(e) {  alert('aaa');  }   );
```

**Re-hydrating a click event handler which has been serialized into a string**

Assuming that you have the code for the original event handler, you can use javascript’s “Function()” to re-hydrate your event handlers that have been serialized into a string.

Possible gotcha: the context of the “new Function()” is always the window context, so your re-hydrated event handlers will break closure (if you are using closures).

Possible gotcha: running strings as functions is dangerously hackable. You intend “alert(‘goodness’)”, but hacker substitutes “alert(‘evil’)”.

```
// bind an event listener that was serialized to a string
var myStringFn="alert('aaa')";
stage.get('#logo').on('click', new Function("event", myStringFn) );
```